# Is there a way to list the commit's author in `git rebase -i` (interactive)?

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I do a `git rebase -i` on a branch shared with a co-worker, I often want to just rebase my own commits.  However, because the interactive rebase tool doesn't add the author information to the rebasing file (all t gives is the commit hash and description), I wind up having to go check commits in another tab to see if they are mine or not.

Is there any way to give `git rebase -i` a `--format` flag (or something like it), to make it include the author?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As of git 2.6, `git rebase -i` uses `rebase.instructionFormat` (default `%s`) to generate the text after `pick NNNNN...`.

Since this is a `git-config` item, you can set the value per repository, for yourself in general, or even using the `-c` option on a one-time basis.

**EDIT:**

As jdknight suggested in the comments, the specific command for this would be:

```
git config --add rebase.instructionFormat "(%an <%ae>) %s"
```

or, to avoid item repetition, as oalders suggested, you can instead set the config globally:

```
git config --global rebase.instructionFormat "(%an <%ae>) %s"
```

Comment: `git config --add rebase.instructionFormat "(%an <%ae>) %s"` (for the lazy)

Comment: Excellent tip.  I've ended up making this a global setting using `git config --global rebase.instructionFormat "(%an <%ae>) %s"`.  I've removed the `--add` since running `git config --add` whenever I install my dot files means having that item show up multiple times in my git configuration.

Answer (score 18):

```
git -c "rebase.instructionFormat=(%an <%ae>) %s" rebase -i COMMIT_HASH
```

Interactive output is going to look as follows:

```
pick b596a7b (Nik Sumeiko <email@example.com>) Refactors type checking utilities
pick c8b815f (Attila Kerekes <email@example.com>) Implements commit message linting
```

Comment: Is this command better in some way than the accepted answer (`git config --add rebase.instructionFormat "(%an <%ae>) %s"`), or is it just another way to skin the cat?

Comment: It's just oneliner to do copy/paste SODD (Stack Overflow Driven Development) 

Answer (score 11):

Edit your `.gitconfig` to add:

```
[rebase]
    instructionFormat = %s [%an]
```

That will show the short commit message and then the author name in square brackets.